# Correlation relation between a normal random vector $(X,Y)$ and its standarizatio $(X',Y')$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution, standard-deviation, correlation

Suppose we have a normal random vector $(X,Y)$ with correlation $\rho$.

If we define $X=\mu_X+\sigma_X X'$ and $Y=\mu_Y+\sigma_Y Y'$, where $\mu$ is the expected value and $\sigma$ is the standard deviation, what would be $\rho(X',Y')$?

Is it $$\rho(X,Y)=\rho(X',Y')?$$

Comment: Please show your effort so far. Did you make an attempt to write $\rho(X,Y)$ in terms of $\rho(X',Y')$

Comment: You have $\rho(X,Y) = C(X,Y)/\sqrt{V(X)V(Y)}$ where $C$ and $V$ denotes covariance and variance respectively. Can you find the covariance and variance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Verify that $\mathsf{Cov}(aX+b,cY+d)=ac\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)$ and (as a corollary) that $\mathsf{Var}(aX+b)=a^2\mathsf{Var}(X)$

Then draw conclusions for $\rho(aX+b,cY+d)$.

Comment: Then, we have that $X'=(X-\mu_X)/\sigma_X$ and the same for $Y'=(Y-\mu_Y)/\sigma_Y$. Hence $cov(X',Y')=\frac{1}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y}cov(X,Y)$. Is that OK?

Comment: Yes, that is okay for covariance. You will see that the factor $\frac1{\sigma_X\sigma_y}$ will nicely disappear if you go for correlation.